# SQL Server : count how many times a record can be applied to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `Tickets` and `Discount`. I have to count how many times the combination of a discount ID can be applied to orders in the `Ticket` table:

`Tickets` table:

```
ITEMID | CATEGORYID
-------+-----------
     1 |         11
     1 |         11
     1 |         11
     2 |         11
     3 |         12
     4 |         13
     4 |         13
     5 |         14
```

`Discounts` table:

```
DiscountID | ITEMID | CATEGORYID
-----------+--------+-----------
         1 |      1 |         11
         1 |      4 |         13
         2 |      1 |         11
         2 |      6 |         15
         3 |      1 |         11
         3 |      5 |         14
```

**Result:** the `DiscountID` 1 can be applied to the `Ticket` table twice, and `DiscountID` 3 can be applied once.

I currently manage to do this via loop in a stored procedure, it is slow as I have to loop through each discount items with all ticket items manually.

I wonder if there is a better way of doing it via SQL with combination of `JOIN` and `INTERSECT`. I couldn't get my head around this, I have to match more than 1 row in the discount table at the same time.

BETTER EXPLANATION:

Original Table without any discount:
`Tickets` table:

```
ITEMID | CATEGORYID
-------+-----------
     1 |         11
     1 |         11
     1 |         11
     2 |         11
     3 |         12
     4 |         13
     4 |         13
     5 |         14
```

Apply Discount ID 1:

```
DiscountID | ITEMID | CATEGORYID
-----------+--------+-----------
         1 |      1 |         11
         1 |      4 |         13
```

Discount ID 1 counted twice because:

```
ITEMID | CATEGORYID
-------+-----------
     1 |         11
     1 |         11
     4 |         13
     4 |         13
```

Now onto Discount ID 2:

```
DiscountID | ITEMID | CATEGORYID
-----------+--------+-----------
         2 |      1 |         11
         2 |      6 |         15
```

With counted DiscountID 1 Items removed:

```
ITEMID | CATEGORYID
-------+-----------
     1 |         11
     2 |         11
     3 |         12
     5 |         14
```

Count for discount ID 2 is 0 because only one record of Dicount ID 2 can be matched in Ticket table  1 |   11

While

6 |         15 is not available in Ticket table. As Discount ID 2 isn't matched nothing is removed from Ticket table

Now onto Discount ID 3:

DiscountID | ITEMID | CATEGORYID
             3 |      1 |         11

```
         3 |      5 |         14


ITEMID | CATEGORYID
-------+-----------
     1 |         11
     2 |         11
     3 |         12
     5 |         14
```

Discount ID 3 is counted once and now with counted records remove will be

```
ITEMID | CATEGORYID
-------+-----------
     2 |         11
     3 |         12
```

As I do not know how to execute above via SQL, I do not know how I can output:

```
DISCOUNTID | APPLIED
-----------+-----------
     1     |   2
     3     |   1
```

Comment: I don't understand where you get your 'Result' from?  Could you explain why it is twice and once?

Comment: It might be easier to understand your requirement if you edit the question to include your existing stored procedure; this would help explain how your matching rules work.

Comment: Hello, for all records in discount table with the same discount ID, these records must exists in the Ticket table to count as once hence Discount ID 1 is applied twice (2 x ITEM ID 1 and 2 x ITEM ID 4; Discount ID 3 can be applied once because (1 x  ITEM ID 1 and 1 x ITEM ID 5). Sorry I should mention any item ID in Ticket table which have discount ID matched to it cannot be reapplied by another discount ID)

Comment: I still don't see why Discountid 3 is not 2, it matches to two different rows, and you've listed the two matches

Comment: Added better explanation above, sorry hope is much clearer now.

Comment: ok, let's o to the part where you say 'With counted DiscountID 1 Items removed:'why have you removed 4 records?  However there is a 1,11 record left, but later you say you can't use it anymore - nothing seems to add up - you need to explain it  more clearly - what are the rules for using tickets again in discounts?

Comment: Each discount ID needs to be applied as a whole (There is two records for Discount ID 1 in Discount table, both of these records must exists in Ticket table to be counted as 1), hence the Ticket table have two 3 times 1 | 11 and 2 times 4 | 13, Discount ID 1 can only be applied twice as the last reamaning 1| 11 does not have 4 | 13 to go with it. When applied the 2 times 1 | 11 and 2 times 4 | 13 is removed from the original table and Discount ID 1 is recorded as applied twice.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick.

```
select distinct d.*
from discounts d
   inner join tickets t on t.itemId = d.itemid 
      and t.categoryId = d.categoryId
```

It will give you

```
DiscountID | ITEMID | CATEGORYID
-----------+--------+-----------
         1 |      1 |         11
         1 |      4 |         13
         2 |      1 |         11
         3 |      5 |         14
```

You can then sum up all the columns as necessary by

`select discountid, count(*) as apply_discount_x_times
from
(
   select distinct d.discountid, d.itemId, d.categoryId
   from discounts d
      inner join tickets t on t.itemId = d.itemid 
         and t.categoryId = d.categoryId
) x
group by discountid`

Giving you

`DiscountID | apply_discount_x_times
-----------+--------
         1 |      2 
         2 |      1 
         3 |      2`

Comment: Hello, for all records in discount table with the same discount ID, these records must exists in the Ticket table to count as once hence Discount ID 1 is applied twice (2 x ITEM ID 1 and 2 x ITEM ID 4; Discount ID 3 can be applied once because (1 x  ITEM ID 1 and 1 x ITEM ID 5). Sorry I should mention any item ID in Ticket table which have discount ID matched to it cannot be reapplied by another discount ID)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. This query will only return you records that have both ids in the ticket table. Maybe add to your question your expected output format?

Comment: you don't seem to have counted anything

Comment: Added an extra step to include count for you

Comment: Added better explanation above, sorry hope is much clearer now.

Comment: The above shed some light on how I can incorporate the above code in my SP to make the SP way faster than before. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped. Did you figure out the answer to get what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct d.*, CA.cnt
from discounts d
  CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT count(0) cnt from tickets t2 
                                join discounts d2 
                                  on d.DiscountId = d2.discountid 
                                     and d2.itemid =  t2.itemid 
                                      and d2.categoryid = t2.categoryid) CA
```